# How can I refresh the access token?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-net

I have a Xamarin.Forms iOS and UWP application based on a .NET standard 2.0 library. I am able to allow the user to a) login with Facebook b) use the received Facebook token to authenticate with an AWS Cognito federated identity pool without any problems leading to a Cognito access token to work with AWS resources for one hour. The logic I follow is to create a new CognitoAWSCredentials instance; call its addLogin method to specify Facebook and the Facebook address token and finally to call the GetIdentityId() method to receive the necessary credentials.

As expected and documented, this access token works for one hour and then I start receiving AmazonCognitoIdentityException.

I have read through the Amazon documentation but did not locate which method or API endpoint to call after (lets say) 55 minutes to refresh this token. Additionally, I also do not see from debug instance inspection any reference to a refresh token or a refresh method.

Guidance to the correct way to refresh the AWS Cognito access token is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to refresh Facebook OAuth2 access token after it expires?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622171/what-is-the-correct-way-to-refresh-facebook-oauth2-access-token-after-it-expires)

Comment: I am talking about refreshing the Cognito token and not the Facebook access token here @ChrisPickford

Comment: I use the Javascript SDK. I have the access, id and refresh token in browser storage. As long as the refresh token is present when a user logs in, the SDK handles refreshing the access and id tokens for me. Might not be the case for Xamarin, I don't know. Can you confirm you have a refresh token in storage? If not, perhaps you problem is that. i.e. I doubt you need to go and refresh tokens yourself, the SDK should handle it.